# how to merge two dataframes if the index and length both do not match?

Tags: python, pandas

i have two data frames predictor_df and solution_df like this :

```
predictor_df
```

1000     A      B    C
  1001     1      2    3
  1002     4      5    6
  1003     7      8    9
  1004    Nan   Nan   Nan

```
and a solution_df
```

0   D 
   1  10
   2  11 
   3  12

the reason for the names is that the predictor_df is used to do some analysis on it's columns to arrive at analysis_df . My analysis leaves the rows with Nan values in predictor_df and hence the **shorter** solution_df

Now i want to know how to join these two dataframes to obtain my final dataframe as

```
  A      B    C    D
  1      2    3   10
  4      5    6   11
  7      8    9   12
 Nan    Nan  Nan
```

please guide me through it . thanks in advance.
Edit : i tried to merge the two dataframes but the result comes like this ,

```
      A      B    C    D
      1      2    3   Nan
      4      5    6   Nan
      7      8    9   Nan
     Nan    Nan  Nan
```

Edit 2 : also when i do `pd.concat([predictor_df, solution_df], axis = 1)`
it becomes like this

```
          A         B      C   D
          Nan      Nan   Nan  10
          Nan      Nan   Nan  11
          Nan      Nan   Nan  12
          Nan      Nan   Nan  Nan
```

Comment: Your example of your desired "final" DataFrame shows a blank cell in the lower right corner, which isn't possible.  Do you want that cell to contain NaN?  How do you know that you want the first row of `solution_df` to match up with the first row of `predictor_df`?  What if `predictor_df` had its row of `NaN` at the end, or in the middle, instead of the beginning?

Comment: @BrenBarn yes sir , i was thinking of adding nothing but since it is not possible Nan or 0 will be a prudent filling to have , also my data set has Nan rows only at the end so that is not the problem

Comment: @Merlin yes i did tried to merge but it throws error as indicated in the edit  to the question :)

Comment: Please show the index for your DataFrames.

Comment: @BrenBarn yaa i guess that is the problem , should i reindex ? thank you for the direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` which resets the index to the default integer index.

```
pd.concat([df_1.reset_index(drop=True), df_2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

     A    B    C     D
0    1    2    3  10.0
1    4    5    6  11.0
2    7    8    9  12.0
3  Nan  Nan  Nan   NaN
```

Comment: yes worked !! :)  i have been searching through 15 pages of pandas documents , you saved my day thanks @nickil